# how can I install libporttime in fedora

Tags: python, fedora

I install pygame for python3.x in my fedora system, and when I run "python3 setup.py install", I got a error: "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lporttime"

So I want to install this libporttime.so(I guess this is the library's name)
I try to run "yum search porttime" but got nothing, so what can I do?

The solution is that you link your libportmidi.so to libporttime.so, that is it.

like: ln -s libportmidi.so libporttime.so

Answer (score -1):

Check This. 
or 
Read Book."**TS7680 Deduplication ProtecTIER Gateway for System z**" Page 155

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -2):

There are two methods:
Install manually by downloading latest package from http://www.time4popcorn.eu/.

Install automatically using rpm package.
But First:
Irrespective of which method you use. You are likely to get the following error regarding libudev.so.0:

$ ./Popcorn-Time: error while loading shared libraries: libudev.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

There is a workaround to fix this error. Create a symlink between libgudev-1.0.so.0 and  libudev.so.0. To create symlink enter the following code:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libgudev-1.0.so.0 /usr/lib64/libudev.so.0
```

If libgudev1 is not installed already, install it:

```
sudo yum install libgudev1
```

Done, you can now proceed installing Popcorn time.

Install manually
Download package for Linux from http://www.time4popcorn.eu/.
Open terminal. Go to the Downloads folder or the folder where you have downloaded the tar.gz package:

```
cd Downloads
```

Extract Popcorn-Time-linux64.tar.gz using the following command:

```
tar -zxvf Popcorn-Time-linux64.tar.gz
```

You can change the file name according to the Downloaded package in above command.

The package I downloaded did not have icon. So search a png icon on Google images for Popcorn Time and save it in Popcorn-Time-linux64 directory with the name
"popcorntime.png"

Now create a directory in /opt for Popcorn Time:

```
sudo mkdir /opt/Popcorn-Time
```

Copy all the files to /opt/Popcorn-Time

```
sudo cp -r Popcorn-Time-linux64/* /opt/Popcorn-Time
```

Now create a menu entry for Popcorn time. So that you can launch it easily:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/popcorntime.desktop
```

Insert the following lines in the text editor (gedit).

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Popcorn Time
Comment=Stream movies from torrents. Skip the downloads. Launch, click, watch
Exec=/opt/Popcorn-Time/Popcorn-Time
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/Popcorn-Time/popcorntime.png
Type=Application
Categories=AudioVideo;
StartupNotify=true
```

Save and Close.
Finished
Install automatically
Download the rpm package from here.
If not found Google  “rpm package for Popcorn-Time”.
Double Click the downloaded package.
Click on Install.
Enter password.
Done
Or Install using commands:

```
cd Downloads

sudo rpm -ivh popcorntime-0.3.3-1.fc20.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: what i want is libporttime, not a Popcorn-Time.